# How to load images or sounds from asset dynamically?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write code that loads images or sounds or else type of document dynamically. I want to show image in ImageView. I tried this:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
try {
    String[] imgPath = assetManager.list("img");
    for (int i = 0; i< imgPath.length; i++) {
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("img/"+imgPath[i]);
        Log.d(TAG, imgPath[i]);
        Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        imageViewbyCode = new ImageView(this);
        imageViewbyCode.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =  new LinearLayout
                        .LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageViewbyCode.setLayoutParams(params);
        myLayout.addView(imageViewbyCode);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: what is your output ?

Answer (score 3):

for sound try:

Create a folder  in project and name it "raw" and put the sound in folder

To play sound:

```
   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.your-sound);
   mp.start();
```

for images i prefere to store images on drawable folder and to get use following code :

```
 Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
              .getIdentifier("imageName", "drawable", getPackageName()));
```